# API Token expires when switching to LIghtning Experience

Tags: lightning, security-token, refresh-token

I have integrated salesforce with my website so that I can use the API's for syncing contacts and leads.

I store the Access token and refresh token in my database and I use them to make API calls with in some duration and the syncing works fine.

But if I login to salesforce and swtich to lighning experience then my API calls does not work. It shows token expired errors.

Why is it so that the tokens fetched in classic view does not work for Lightning view?

Comment: Can you not just use the refresh token to get a new valid Session?

Comment: I am using the refresh token to generate a new token but that is also showing me error that Access Token/Refresh Token expired.